# JavaScript hide and show toggle, hide DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

For the following example, how would I start the page off by hiding the 'divToToggle' DIV as it is currently showing on default? I do not want to use 'display:none;' outside of the script for accessibility reasons. How do you hide the 'divToToggle' within the script on startup?
Thanks.

```
            <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
            <html>
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <title>JavaScript hide and show toggle</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body>
            <script>
            function toggleAndChangeText() {
                 $('#divToToggle').toggle();
                 if ($('#divToToggle').css('display') == 'none') {
                      $('#aTag').html('[+] Show text');
                 }
                 else {
                      $('#aTag').html('[-] Hide text');
                 }
            }
            </script>
            <br>
            <a id="aTag" href="javascript:toggleAndChangeText();">[-] Hide text</A> 
            <div id="divToToggle">Content that will be shown or hidden.</div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the hide function inside a document.ready function

```
$(function(){
     $('#divToToggle').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thank you David and wirey.

What I was after was the hide function but wasn't sure how to mark it up correctly, thank you for the snippet wirey.

Answer (score 0):

Just use jQuery, since you're already using it (and this way doesn't prevent non-JS users from seeing the element):

```
function toggleAndChangeText() {
     $('#divToToggle').toggle();
     if ($('#divToToggle').css('display') == 'none') {
          $('#aTag').html('[+] Show text');
     }
     else {
          $('#aTag').html('[-] Hide text');
     }
}

$('#divToToggle').hide();
// the rest of your script(s)...
```

Also, a minor update to your toggle function:

```
function toggleAndChangeText() {
    // because you're accessing this element more than once,
    // it should be cached to save future DOM look-ups
    var divToToggle = $('#divToToggle');
    divToToggle.toggle();
    // You're not changing the HTML, just the text, so use the
    // appropriate method (though it's a *minor* change)
    $('#aTag').text(function() {
        // if the element is visible change the text to
        // '...hide...'; if not, change the text to '...show...'
        return divToToggle.is(':visible') ? '[-] Hide text' : '[+] Show Text';
    });
}
```

References:

- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
- [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`:visible` selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).